# How to show a toast and clear input when data from dropdown is repeated?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an inpput, when i write a order number and if it exist on database it show me a notification and input clear, but when i select from dropdown it print on input but it isnt show me the notification and the input no clear pls help me if it exist a form to do that

**HERES MY DROPDOWN**

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text"
                                               class="form-control"
                                               name="codigoOrdenTrabajo"
                                               id="codigoOrdenTrabajo"
                                               minlength="5"
                                               maxlength="5"
                                               required
                                               style="width: 30px">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button type="button"
                                                    class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle"
                                                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                                                    aria-expanded="false">
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                                                 id="opcionesCodigoOrdenTrabajo">
                                                <?php

                                                    $item = null;
                                                    $valor = null;

                                                    $orden = ControladorOrdenTrabajo::ctrMostrarOrdenTrabajo($item, $valor);

                                                    foreach ($orden as $value) {

                                                        echo '<a class="dropdown-item"
                                                   href="#">' . $value["codigoOrdenTrabajo"] . '</a>';

                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
```

**HERES MY JAVASCRIPT** when i capture the value of the input and print on to the input and the next code its the calling when i repeat the code manually on the input

```
 /*==================================
    OBTENER EL VALOR DEL DROPDOWN E IMPRIMIRLO EN EL INPUT
    ==================================*/
    $(document).on("click", "#opcionesCodigoOrdenTrabajo > a", setDropdownValue);

    function setDropdownValue() {

        let $option = $(this);

        $option.closest(".input-group").find("input").val($option.text());

    }

    /*=============================
    REVISAR SI LA ORDEN DE TRABAJO YA HA SIDO REGISTRADA
    =============================*/
    $('#codigoOrdenTrabajo').change(function () {

        let ordenTrabajo = $(this).val(),
            datos = new FormData();

        //name: = adicionar variable POST
        datos.append('validarOrdenTrabajo', ordenTrabajo);

        $.ajax({

            url: "ajax/transacciones_ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (respuesta) {

                if (respuesta) {

                    toastr.error(
                        'El numero de orden ya existe en la base de datos',
                        '',
                        {
                            timeOut: 2000,
                            fadeOut: 2000,
                        }
                    );
                    $('#codigoOrdenTrabajo').val("");

                }

                //REVISAR LO QUE VIENE DESDE LA BDD
                /*console.log("respuesta", respuesta);*/

            }
        });
    });
```